# vpn client for iphone/ipad

Tags: iphone, ios4, ipad, vpn

I want to implement vpn client applcation for iphone and ipad.
my requirement is to develope an application to enter vpn details and to show the network traffic and the connection.
can anyone please help me in this, how to implement vpn client on iOS.

Comment: VPN is already built into the iPhone, I believe. If you're talking about VPN network monitoring it's a different story. Good luck.

Comment: you are rite..vpn is already built into the iphone. but my client need his proprietery app through which user should be able to connect to the client network...and through which we should monitor the network as well...please share me ..if you have any idea on this..

Comment: Hi. Did you find an answer? I'm bothered with the same question. Please answer.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the VPN API is not exposed in the Apple iOS.

http://blog.michael.kuron-germany.de/2010/09/ios-4-1-undocumented-vpn-api-used-by-cisco-anyconnect/

Answer (score 2):

Officially, since it's built right into the phone, it most likely won't fly with Apple. Can't you just watch the traffic going through the VPN server instead of watching it at the client?

Comment: yes..we can do it..but..my client requirement is he wants an app like F5-Edge client / cisco-Anyconnect... to develop these kind of application could you please tell me what kind of API's i should use from sdk so that i can connect to network through vpn..

Answer (score 0):

Did you hear about iConn VPN Client? It is available in apple store and though it is free. You can download the client into your IOS device and i hope that it will work for you.

Comment: Answer after reading entire conversation.. It is already said in comment about VPN client app availability...